# How can we calculate the number of days between two dates in oracle-sql ? exact syntax?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried this

```
select datediff(day,doi,dateeg) from Cardholders;
```

error:ORA-00904 : "DATEDIFF" invalid identifier

here doi and dateeg are of date datatype in cardholders relation ?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, just use subtraction.  This will probably do what you want:

```
select trunc(dateeg) - trunc(doi) from Cardholders
```